# Обучение C# с нуля

Tags: c#, .net, unity3d, visual-studio

Всем привет, Я решил начать свой путь программирования с языка c#, на данный момент учу синтаксис при помощи видео-уроков на YouTube, паралельно читая Герберта Шилдта, но не особо понимаю, как мне применять полученные знания, помимо написания простых консольных программ, вот и возник сам вопрос, как начать правильно практиковаться, какие задачи или проекты брать? Есть ли какие-то источники для этого?

Comment: https://github.com/karan/Projects   ....   https://github.com/practical-tutorials/project-based-learning#c   ..... да  любые списки проектов найдите в сети.... от калькулятора, до складского учёта

Comment: Начните с языка ассемблера, основы никогда не бывают лишними

Comment: @Aarnihauta, вы начинали с Ассемблера?

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato ни в коем случае, мой рассудок мне дороже

Comment: @Aarnihauta, Зачем советуете тогда? Если это шутка, я её не понял.

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato основы никогда не бывают лишними, поэтому и советую

Comment: @Aarnihauta, советуете начать с Ассемблера?

Comment: @Aarnihauta извиняюсь, но Ассемблер - это далеко не основы разработки. Как работает железо знать надо, но это совсем не требуется новичку. Тем более, если он игры писать собрался.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Изучите основы и синтаксис ЯП
2. Придумайте проект
3. Определитесь что нужно для проекта(какая литература, какие средства разработки нужны итд)
4. В свободное время творите...
5. Столкнувшись с проблемой старайтесь решить её не списав под чистую. Пробуйте решить своими силами.
6. Читайте документацию. Ещё больше документации....(если она есть ^.^)
7. Не забывайте возвращаться к литературе. (с неё бы и начать)
8. YouTube - в последнюю очередь!!!(имхо)